# show form onclick inside a div

Tags: jquery

thanks for reading.

I have list of comments and each comment has a reply link. When you click on the link a form for that individual comment should be displayed.

I'm so confused. I wrote this jquery but  i know it does not even make sense.

```
  <script>
     $('.reply-comment').click(function(){

    var CommentID = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).hide();
    $('.reply-comment-form').show( function(){
        $('.reply-comment-form-'+CommentID).html();
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

here is the form

```
    <div class="reply-comment-form well">';
     <form name="reply-form" id="reply-form" method="POST">
      <textarea name="Comment" rows="6" class="span10"></textarea> <br />
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary replycommentsubmitbutton" value="Yanitla" />
     </form>
    </div>
```

and I added a span under every comment for the form to display

```
<div>
      comments text etc etc...
</div>
   <a href="" class="reply-comment" id="<?php $v['CommentID'] ?>"> Reply </a>
   <span id="reply-fomment-form-<?php $v['CommentsID'] ?>"></span>
```

so, how do I use show() function with html() function or is there another approach for this?

Could you please help me? thanks.

Comment: @SheikhHeera added into answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate all the forms and keep those forms hidden, for example

**HTML:**

```
<div>comments text etc etc...</div>
<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="<?php $v['CommentID'] ?>"> Reply </a>
<form class="reply-form">
    <input />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<br />
<div>comments text etc etc...</div>
<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="<?php $v['CommentID'] ?>"> Reply </a>
<form class="reply-form">
    <input />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.reply-form{ display:none; }
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.reply-comment').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.reply-form').show();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Zv3uy/) [**Updated Demo using OP's markup.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Zv3uy/1/)

Comment: thanks. this works. so, this is the right approach for this kind of problems? I'm trying to learn these things. Thanks.

Comment: Check this [updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Zv3uy/1/), using your form code and Welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use relative selectors and forget the whole ID-thing.

```
$('.reply-comment').click(function(){
   $(this).next('.reply-comment-form').show()
})
```